# iOS 6 – Force a rotation for a UIViewController inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a `UINavigationController` where all `UIViewController` in the stack are portrait, except the last one, which is landscape. My current implementation shows the last view controller in portrait on push, but I can rotate to landscape, and the, cannot rotate back to portrait. **How can I force the rotation to landscape when the view is pushed ?**

My `UINavigationController` subclass :

```
@interface RotationViewController : UINavigationController

@end

@implementation RotationViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.topViewController.class == [LoadingViewController class])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if (self.topViewController.class == [LoadingViewController class])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

The view controller that I want landscape-only :

```
@implementation LoadingViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

@end
```

Other view controllers don't implement any of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same condition. So You can implement the below code in your application

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(270));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 480, 44.0); 
} 

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];   

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 480);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0);
}

#define degreesToRadian(X) (M_PI * (X)/180.0)
```

Note:-

**The above code is implement for the iphone. So Please change the bounds if you use this for ipad.**

You need not to implement the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

functions in your view controller.... So remove those methods....

Comment: It works (I just had to return 0 from my navigation controller supportedInterfaceOrientation), but I was looking for an answer on how to trigger automatic rotation when pushing the view. This solutions is more a trick...

Comment: Works great for reorienting the screen! But for some reason the statusbar is still at the top. When I reorient the device to match the screen, the statusbar goes to the right place, but when I go back to the original portrait orientation, the screen goes portrait. (None of this was affected by `supportedInterfaceOrientation`'s presence/absence.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the question [How to handle different orientations in iOS 6.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947349/how-to-handle-different-orientations-in-ios-6) See the answer there for a project example of exactly what you need.

Basically you need to embed a custom navigation controller in your viewcontroller (the one you want to rotate). Add the following method in this custom navigation controller

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

and add to your view controller that should rotate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Be sure Portrait, Landscape Right and Landscape Left orientations are enabled in your project. Then, if you want to block some orientations for a particular view:

```
– application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
```