# How to manage Orientation on View Controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

First I selected Device Orientation portrait ,Landscape Left and Landscape Right ...then assume I am using five ViewControllers Now First three ViewController and fifth ViewController I want only Portrait and fourth View Controller we want `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` so I am using this code ...

For first three ViewController and Fifth ViewController

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
  }
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
 {
  return YES;
 }
```

for fourth View Controller

```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
  }
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
 {
  return YES;
 }
```

This Problem is when we rotate fourth view controller in landscape (left or right) this rotate successfully but when we go next View Controller then fifth view controller not become in  Portrait mode .if i am go back from fourth view Controller to  third view controller it will automatically rotate third view controller into Portrait mode but when we go form fourth view controller to fifth view controller it will not convert in Portrait mode.solve this problem.
  actually when tap back button on navigation bar then above two method call automatic but when we tap right navigation bar button for push next view controller then these method not call automatically so i don't know how to use this.

Comment: its pretty bad behaviour of application from user point of view, try to support only one orientation or both, not some random

Comment: Did you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041650/ios7-ios6-conditional-rotation-portrait-landscape-for-different-sections-of