# Set UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight for a specific view controller in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to open a sepcific view controller of my application always in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. No other orientantion. How can I do this in iOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewController`'s `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations

Comment: Not working bro. Not sure, but I guess it is something with CGAffineTransform.

Comment: How do you switch viewcontrollers?

Comment: The view controller I am talking about is, switched from the root view controller by 'presentViewController'.

Comment: This question has solution how to force an orientation change when switching between view  controllers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041650/ios7-ios6-conditional-rotation-portrait-landscape-for-different-sections-of

Comment: You can try `shouldAutorotate` return `YES` with `supportedInterfaceOrientations `.

Comment: `shouldAutorotate` returns `YES` by default

Answer (score 0):

irst import this

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

and in viewDidAppear

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
           objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
}
```