# How to set Portrait mode when view appear in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

I used below code, it works fine ios 6 but when in Xcode 5(ios7), it has error so I can not build project. Is there another way to set to Portrait view when viewcontroller appear? Please help me. Thanks

```
CGFloat ios = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
CGFloat min = 5.0;
if (ios >= min)
{
    if (self.interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
        {
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
            [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
            [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle different orientations in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947349/how-to-handle-different-orientations-in-ios-6)

Comment: See my answer to the question above. Should help you.

Comment: @LeoNatan: Thanks,but it not work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape check this link might help you

Answer (score 0):

Use have set the this on info plist.

from plist choose

Supported interface orientations (iPad)-->add item as Portrait (bottom home button)

and add this code

```
     -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
      {

           return NO;
      }

         -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
        {
          return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;;
         }
```