# iOS 7 Orientation not working

Tags: ios, ios7

Team,

My application is not responding to Orientations from iOS 7 onwards. I was trying to push the screen through pushViewController, then later I changed to presentViewController

before
        `[viewController.navigationController pushViewController:landscapeCommentScreen animated:animated];`

After iOS7 upgrade:

```
 [viewController.navigationController presentViewController:landscapeCommentScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

added the below methods in view controller

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` in `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. You should return `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

Comment: @RameshSangili Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16022631/983912 for a full example project with exactly what you need.

Comment: I tried, it is not working. I am building the UI screens on top of a framework, I am not sure whether is restricting the Orientation support. Is there anyways to override the code in the framework to support for orientation change? I did a sample application and there it works fine.

Comment: @RameshSangili If the framework opens your view controller in modal, that should be enough for your to control the orientation of your view controller.

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried a sample application using my framework and device responds to Orientation change. But When I try with this application which was already built by other developers, I am seeing an issue wit Orientation. The device always shows in Portrait mode irrespective of the Orientation change. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the app defines only portrait orientation as supported in its plist.

Comment: We already added for LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight in Plist file and also in General Settings to support for Landscape Left and Right

Comment: I resolved the issue with 3rd party framework, 

I just would like to know, how to enable Landscape Orientation only on Specific screens? As of now, I selected Landscape Left and Right options in General Settings and enabled in Supported interface orientations (iPhone) in plist file for the device Orientation, but that impacts all the screens.

I have nearly 80 screens in my application, I need to support both Portrait and Landscape about 5 screens, rest of the screens should be shown only in Portrait mode.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Ramesh

Comment: @RameshSangili See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16022631/983912 including an example project.

Comment: Thank you Leo. Am I suppose to override the below method in 80 screens?
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with your design. In a case like this, I would create a subclass of `UIViewController` and implement there, and use that as my subclass for the view controllers in question.

Comment: Hi Leo, our framework extend UIViewController and we extend FramewworkUIViewController class to design the screen. I added a category to FrameworkUIViewCOntroller and added the supportedInterfaceOrientation to lock it only portrait mode, but that is not working :(...

Comment: view controller is pushed.. I added a category and override AutoRotate and supportInterfaceOrientations, but what I observed shouldAutoRotate is not being called at all, it calls only supportInterfaceOrientation.. Any idea why?

Comment: You cannot enforce an orientation when a view controller is pushed. Did you read my answer in the link? It will only work on modally presented view controllers.