# Rotation IOS Simulator vs Reality

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I am having issues with Storyboards AutoRotation and the iPhone.  I've put together a VERY simple project with 3 view controllers which I uploaded to gitHub to demonstrate the issue

I've tested this on the following devices:

- IPAD 3
- IPHONE 5s
- Simulator (iphone / ipad)

Everything seems to work perfectly on the iPad & Simulator (Iphone/Ipad) but when I run it on the 5s it does not rotate correctly.

On the iPhone it will rotate the alert view but not the view controller it appears
[image: IPHONE]

On the simulator this is the result (which looks correct)
[image]

Code for sample project can be found at:
https://github.com/jlss/RotationIssues

I am happy and willing to try ANY suggestions anybody has.

Things of Note:  (I am using the call `objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);` ) but as far as I can tell this should be ok.

**RotationControlledViewController.m**

```
//
//  RotationControlledViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RotationControlledViewController.h"

@interface RotationControlledViewController ()

@end

@implementation RotationControlledViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    BOOL ret =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
//    NSLog(@"--Auto Roatate Reported %d", ret);
    return ret;
}



-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger ret = [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];

//    NSLog(@"--supportedInterfaceOrientations: %d", ret);


    return ret;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation ret =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

//    NSLog(@"--preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: %ld",ret);
    return ret;
}


@end
```

**PortraitViewController.m**

```
//
//  PortraitViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PortraitViewController.h"
#import "objc/message.h"

@interface PortraitViewController ()

@end

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Portrait Alert" message:@"This is portrait view" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}



@end
```

**LandscapeViewController**

```
//
//  LandscapeViewController.m
//  ASGAARD
//
//  Created by Jeff Stein on 2/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jeff Stein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LandscapeViewController.h"
#import "objc/message.h"

@interface LandscapeViewController ()

@end

@implementation LandscapeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

    NSLog(@"Issuing a rotation message (hopefully");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Landscape Alert" message:@"This is landscape view" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

@end
```

And lastly i have a simple storyboard with:

[image]

Comment: `setOrientation:` is private API and can result in removal from the store and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Leo So what would you suggest instead? - Also this app will never go to the store.  Furtehrmore MANY answers on here refer to that API

Comment: Yes, many answers refer to it, but that does not mean it's correct - you have hit a problem due to using it. If you will not be uploading to the appstore, it's less of a problem, but still better to use the proper API. When you want to force a specific orientation, the best method is to use modal presentation.

Comment: Can you offer an example snippet or point somewhere useful?

Comment: Also how is this an illegal API:  its right here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend

Comment: I think you posted a wrong link. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947349/how-to-handle-different-orientations-in-ios/16022631#16022631) for an explanation and example project.

Comment: The problem is not calling `objc_msgSend`, it's about sending a message to `setOrientation`, which is private API.

Comment: This approach also doesn't seem to work well (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15057537/2069812) i guess there is no way to do it in IOS7

Comment: My linked solution works well when used correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this if you are using push segues. You have to use modal.